# ES6 Classes - Chain Select

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

I'm struggling for a time to find the best way to create a chain select. I can't figure out how to load in on Tier another Tier and also pass it to the group of tiers (also I try to respect the single responsibility principle).

**Here is what I am trying to make:**

- first tier will show on load
- on changing a tier his sub tier will load
- in the group it needs to be all loaded tiers
- it must an infinite number of tiers

[image]

**Here is what made so far:**

```
class TierGroup {

  constructor() {
        this.$tiersContainer = $('#tiers');
        this.group =[];
        this.createTier();

  }

  createTier() {

        let tier = new Tier();
        tier.$select.on('change', e => {

            let tier =new Tier();

            tier.$select.on('change', e => {
                    let tier =new Tier();
                    this.group.push(tier);
                    this.$tiersContainer.append(tier.$select);

            });

            this.group.push(tier);
            this.$tiersContainer.append(tier.$select);

        });

        this.$tiersContainer.append(tier.$select);
        this.group.push(tier);

  }  

}

class Tier {
  constructor() {
    this.$select =$('<select/>');
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => {
      for (let row in res.data) {
        this.$select.append('<option>'+res.data[row].name+'</option>')
      }
    })
  }

}


var tier =new TierGroup();
```

https://jsbin.com/buziyu/edit?html,js,output

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got the problem... if it is "I would like to have an infinite chain without manual infinite nesting" this is my solution.

The enforcement of the Single Responsibility Principle is the key to solve this in fact :)

As you can see in your code, the `createTier` method is doing four things (which is too much):

- creates a new tier;
- attaches an handler on it (with it's own definition, way tooo much);
- append the brand new tier to the group and the dom;
- coordinate these steps.

I would take out from this method two separate ones for:

1. the creation of a tier with it's handler;
2. the appending of a tier.

Taken in isolation, the preparation of a tier can be something like:

```
buildTier() {
  let tier = new Tier();
  tier.$select.on('change', /* something here */)
  return tier
}
```

The appending of a tier, instead, could be something like:

```
appendTier(tier) {
  this.$tiersContainer.append(tier.$select);
  this.group.push(tier);
}
```

Now, let leave the job of coordinating this stuff to the createTier, it would become:

```
createTier() {
  const newTier = this.buildTier()
  this.appendTier(newTier)
}
```

or even:

```
createTier() {
  this.appendTier(this.buildTier())
}
```

As you can see, each method does just one thing. The interesting part is that nowhere a tier is linked to it's descendant or parent, meaning that we can use the `createTier` as the handler for a selection, paying attention to pass down the current context:

```
buildTier() {
  let tier = new Tier();
  tier.$select.on('change', this.createTier.bind(this))
  return tier
}
```

Hope it helps :)

https://jsbin.com/wuviqoxohu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Sorry for my confusing description. You solution is exact what I needed, awesome! thanks for u time! I was pretty close, but my brain just got stuck on that callback for on select event, I have been missing that bind. I'm very curiously how / from where did you learn this kind of stuff, because I searched for this solution a lot without any response. Do u recommend some books, tutorials ? thanks again! have a nice day

Comment: Glad to help :). I would suggest You Don't Know JS book series and the Deep Javascript Foundations course on Frontend Masters, both by getify ;)